# Query is taking more time than expected

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

I have a query which is taking 18 seconds to return a result, which is unexpected. This needs to be optimized. The query is using two tables, only with one nested query. What are the best possible ways to optimize it?

Can some one please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: below query - how below? underneath your computer machine?

Comment: Show us the query, the table and index definitions, and the explain plan.

Comment: Any chance to see that query and the table definitions?

Answer (score 0):

An [Explain Plan](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231) will describe what the database is doing to retrieve the data, this is something that can be viewed in Oracle SQL Developer by hitting F10 when your query is in the window. Most likely you want the cost value to be as low as possible.

Making sure the tables have valid primary key, foreign key relationships will help as the amount of data scales up in the tables.

If the tables do have relationships defined, you can check if you need to [Rebuild Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/alter-index-rebuild.htm#SPATL1017) if they have become stale.

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice if you could post your query here and the table structure.

But the best way of optimizing a Query start with optimizing the Tables.

1. They Both need to have a primary key
2. If needed Index the key which you use on your where clause.

How long does a nested query take? might be a reason as well.